# Access vue vuex namespaced getter from template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have made vuex namespaced getter mapping in my `.vue` component like this:

```
...mapGetters([
  'fooModule/barGetter'
])
```

How do I access this getter in the `.vue` component template?
I have tried `{{fooModule.barGetter}}` but it doesn't seem to work, `{{fooModule/barGetter}}` is obviously wrong.

I could assign another key to the getter in `mapGetters` by

```
...mapGetters({
    fooBarGetter: 'fooModule/barGetter'
})
```

This allows me to access the value in the template by using `{{forBarGetter}}`

However, I am wondering if there is a way to access the `'fooModule/barGetter'` without assigning it another key. Is it possible? if so how?

Comment: Read [this](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html) documantation page about `getters`. It explained everything.

Comment: Thanks @ironcladgeek for the docs link. I have read through the documentation already. One way to work around this issue is to assign a key in ...mapGetters by doing:

`
...mapGetters({fooBarGetter: 'fooModule/barGetter'})
`

Then i can access the value from the template with {{forBarGetter}}

But I would like to know if it would be possible to use the getter in the template without assigning another key

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific. Hope that helps

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The first parameter of `mapGetters` can be a namespace:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters("fooModule", [
        "barGetter"
    ]),
    ...mapGetters("anotherModule", [
        "someGetter"
    ])
}
```

That will make the value available as `this.barGetter` or just `barGetter` in templates. Note, it's perfectly acceptable to have multiple `mapGetters` statements.

[Vuex Getters documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html)

[Vuex Binding helpers with namespace](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace)

Comment: This isn't working for me...also the documentation linked in this answer does not link to namespaced Getters. There's slight nuances between the two from what I can see.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos Namespaced getters should work just the same. The helpers will properly add "/" between namespaces. Additional information can be found here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace

Answer (score 4):

Well actually it's registered under the key `'fooModule/barGetter'`, which is not a valid name for a javascript variable. So you should access the key as a string, ah, and so, it's not so elegant. But you can still do it, access it in the template with `{{ _self['fooModule/barGetter'] }}`.

See this working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      fooModule: {
        namespaced: true,
        state: {},
        getters: {
          barGetter() {
            return 'Hi :)';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }),
  computed: Vuex.mapGetters([
    'fooModule/barGetter'
  ])
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.1/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.3.1"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ _self['fooModule/barGetter'] }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who wants to achieve this without specifying the namespace as a first parameter, there's also a possibility to pass `object/map` to mapGetters with **already namespaced names of the getter**s.

```js
...mapGetters({
    'activeItems': ACTIVE_ITEMS_GETTER_WITH_NAMESPACE
})
```

This is extremely useful when you have constants with namespaced names of mutations, getters and actions. In our case, we have lots of modules and it sometimes time consuming to look up the module our getter, mutation or action is inside. This is why we add namespace to our constants.

Comment: This has never worked for me, so in this case is should `ACTIVE_ITEMS_GETTER_WITH_NAMESPACE` be `fooModule/barGetter`?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.$store.getters.productName
```

in template, ex:

```
<vs-td width="20%">{{$store.getters.productName}}</vs-td>
```